# Unique regex for name validation

Tags: php, regex, validation

I want to check is the name valid with regex PHP, but i need a unique regex that allows:

- Letters (upper and lowercase)
- Spaces (max 2)

But there can't be a space after space..
For example:
Name -> Dennis Unge Shishic (valid)
Name -> Denis(space)(space) (not valid)

Hope you guys understand me, thank you :)

Comment: post your attempt please

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? `^[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+(\s[a-zA-Z])?$` maybe or is first name alone valid?

Comment: I didn't try any regex because i couldn't find anything..

Comment: Can you provide more examples of what is and isn't valid?

Comment: There can be a first name and last name, but it can also be a first name - middle name - last name..So both can be valid..And there can ONLY be 1 or 2 spaces (not more or not less).. For example:
John Smith (valid) (contains 1 space)
John Deny Smith (valid) (contains 2 space)

Comment: Can you please check my answer..may be it is helpful to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it's worth mentioning that having such restrictive rules for the names of persons is [a very bad idea](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).  However, if you must, a simple character class like this will limit you to just uppercase and lowercase English letters:

```
[A-Za-z]
```

To match one or more, you need to add a `+` after it.  So, this will match the first part of the name:

```
[A-Za-z]+
```

To capture a second name, you just need to do the same thing preceded by a space, so something like this will capture two names:

```
[A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+
```

To make the second name optional, you need to surround it by parentheses and add a `?` after it, like this:

```
[A-Za-z]+( [A-Za-z]+)?
```

And to add a third name, you just need to do it again:

```
[A-Za-z]+( [A-Za-z]+)? [A-Za-z]+
```

Or, you could specify that the latter names can repeat between 1 and 2 times, like this:

```
[A-Za-z]+( [A-Za-z]+){1,2}
```

Comment: using `[A-Za-z]*( [A-Za-z]+)?( [A-Za-z]+)?` may be more apt here..because your regex won't match if there is space in starting..

Comment: @rock321987 I assumed, based on the wording of the question, that spaces at the beginning were invalid.

Comment: yeah..what I suggested won't match if there is space in last..anyhow I think your assumption is correct

Comment: It's hard to explain what i want..I want it to be valid even with 1 or 2 spaces.Name can contain first name and last name, and it can contain first name - middle name - last name.. So there must be 1 or 2 spaces, not more, not less..And also spaces can't be typed first, or space after space (Name then 2 spaces)..

Comment: Ok. I've updated my answer to reflect that requirement

Comment: Thank you for answer, i needed this: if(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z]+( [A-Za-z]+)? [A-Za-z]+$/i", $name) echo "Invalid name";

Answer (score 0):

To make the resulting code easy to understand and maintain, you could use two Regex. One checking (by requiring it to be true) that only the allowed characters are used `^[a-zA-Z ]+$` and then another one, checking (by requiring it to be false) that there are no two (or more) adjacent spaces `( ){2,}`

Answer (score 0):

**Try following working code:**
Change input to whatever you want to test and see correct validation result printed

```
<?php

$input_line = "Abhishek  Gupta";
preg_match("/[a-zA-Z ]+/", $input_line, $nameMatch);
preg_match("/\s{2,}/", $input_line, $multiSpace);

var_dump($nameMatch);
var_dump($multiSpace);

if(count($nameMatch)>0){

   if(count($multiSpace)>0){
    echo "Invalid Name Multispace";
    }
    else{
    echo "Valid Name";
    }
}
else{
echo "Invalid Name";
}

?>
```

Comment: Name -> "AbhishekGupta" -> Valid (shouldn't be)
Name -> " AbhishekGupta" -> Valid (shouldn't be)
Name -> "AbhishekGupta " -> Valid (shouldn't be)
Name -> "Abhishek Gupta" -> Valid (should be)
Name -> "Abhishek John Gupta" -> Valid (should be)

Answer (score 0):

A regex for one to three words consisting of only Unicode letters in PHP looks like

```
/^\p{L}+(?:\h\p{L}+){1,2}\z/u
```

Description:

- `^` - string start
- `\p{L}+` - one or more Unicode letters
- `(?:\h\p{L}+){1,2}` - one or two sequences of a horizontal whitespace followed with one or more Unicode letters
- `\z` - end of string, even disallowing trailing newline that a dollar anchor allows.